# Where can I find a list with beaches which include coordinates?

Tags: data, api, geolocation, point-of-interest

I use World Weather Online marine API to get wave height of different beaches. This API provide data by coordinates and I need a list with coordinates of beaches.

Comment: Where (what beaches are you targeting)?

Comment: I am interested in US beaches

Answer (score 1):

An all encompassing list of this information may be hard to find.  One option would be to compile your own list using a site like [latlong.net](http://www.latlong.net/) or using something like Google Earth.  Just zoom in close and record the lng/lat coordinates.